# How to get subdomain of URL in NGINX

Tags: nginx, redirect, devops

I am wanting to do a redirect based on what subdomain the user is entering.

For example:

`<subdomain>.example.com/admin -> <subdomain>.myurl.com`

Ideally I want to pass `<subdomain>` as a parameter to my redirect URL.

I was looking at something along the lines of this:

```
location ~ (sub).(somewhere).(com)/(some)(thing)/(something)(else) {
  set $var1 = $1; # = sub in above example
  set $var2 = $2; # = somewhere in above example
  set $var3 = $3; # = com in above example
  set $var4 = $4; # = some in above example
  set $var5 = $5; # = thing in above example
  set $var6 = $6; # = something in above example
  set $var7 = $7; # = else in above example
  rewrite ^ $1/$2 last; # would be sub/somewhere
}
```

based on this post here: [Manipulate or split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051810/manipulate-or-split-string) (I think the syntax of the variable set is wrong in this example but you get the gist).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The domain name part of the URL is not tested by the `location` directive. You will need to use a named capture in the `server_name` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<name>\w+)\.example\.com$;

    location /admin {
        return 301 $scheme://$name.myurl.com/;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the sounds of it, what I am asking for may not be possible then.

Ideally I want to put it within the server block that already has the server_name set and then if it is `<subdomain1>.example.com/admin -> <subdomain1>.myurl.com` or if it is `<subdomain2>.example.com/admin -> <subdomain2>.myurl.com`

I can hard code it for each one but we run a few sites like this where we redirect our react frontend to a admin panel which sits on the API url so would be good to have a generic config.

Comment: The Regex doesn't match urls with `-` in URL. Better would be to use: `server_name ~^(?<name>[\w-]+)\.example\.com$;`